# Integral $\int_0^1\frac{1-x^2+\left(1+x^2\right)\ln x}{\left(x+x^2\right)\ln^3x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I'm struggling with this integral
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^2+\left(1+x^2\right)\ln x}{\left(x+x^2\right)\ln^3x}dx.\tag1$$
*Mathematica* could not evaluate it in a closed form. Its numeric value is approximately $I\approx0.7804287418294087023386965471512328112...$[$^\text{[more]}$](http://goo.gl/3bqoeT), but I could not find a plausible closed form for this number using inverse symbolic calculators available online.

---

*Update*: Based on [Raymond Manzoni's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21783/raymond-manzoni) comment below, there is actually a conjectural closed form, numerically matching up to at least $10^3$ decimal digits:
$$I\stackrel?=6\ln A-\frac{\ln4}3-\frac14,\tag2$$
where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html):
$$A=\exp\left(\frac1{12}-\zeta'(-1)\right).\tag3$$
Could you suggest a proof of the conjecture $(2)$?

Comment: I'll conjecture that the answer is $$\displaystyle \frac 14-\frac 23\log(2)-6\zeta'(-1)$$ (correct to the $1000$ digits provided).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni How did you discover this closed form? BTW, it can be expressed using [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html) as $6\ln A-\frac23\ln2-\frac14$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: I searched linear dependencies using PSLQ and my own tables. I noticed too the relation with G-K constant but without direct integral transformation I could see yet. Cheers,

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We start from [the first Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html):
$$\ln\Gamma(z)=\left(z-\tfrac12\right)\ln z-z+\frac{\ln(2\pi)}2+\int_0^\infty\left(\frac12-\frac1t+\frac1{e^t-1}\right)\frac{e^{-t\,z}}t dt.\tag1$$
Change variable $t=-2\ln x$:
$$\ln\Gamma(z)=\left(z-\tfrac12\right)\ln z-z+\frac{\ln(2\pi)}2+\frac12\int_0^1x^{2z-1}\frac{1-x^2+(1+x^2)\ln x}{(x^2-1)\ln^2x}dx.\tag2$$
Integrate on interval $0<z<\frac12$:
$$\psi^{(-2)}\left(\tfrac12\right)=\frac1{16}+\frac{\ln8}8+\frac{\ln\pi}4+\frac14\int_0^1\frac{1-x^2+(1+x^2)\ln x}{(x+x^2)\ln^3x}dx.\tag3$$
Use formula $(5)$ from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) connecting Barnes G-Function and negapolygamma, and let $z=\frac12$:
$$\ln G\left(\tfrac12\right)=\frac{\ln(2\pi)}4+\frac18-\frac{\ln\pi}4-\psi^{(-2)}\left(\tfrac12\right).\tag4$$
Use formula $(19)$ from the [same page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) to get a closed form for $\ln G\left(\tfrac12\right)$ in terms of the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html) $A$:
$$\ln G\left(\tfrac12\right)=-\frac{3\ln A}2-\frac{\ln\pi}4+\frac18+\frac{\ln2}{24}.\tag5$$
Comparing $(4)$ and $(5)$ we can get:
$$\psi^{(-2)}\left(\tfrac12\right)=\frac{3\ln A}2+\frac{\ln\pi}4+\frac{5\ln2}{24}\tag6.$$
Finally, from $(3)$ and $(6)$ it follows:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-x^2+(1+x^2)\ln x}{(x+x^2)\ln^3x}dx=6\ln A-\frac{\ln4}3-\frac14,\tag7$$
that proves the conjecture.

Answer (score 25):

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int^1_0\frac{1-x^2+(1+x^2)\log x}{x+1}\frac{dx}{x\log^3x}\\
&=\left.\frac{-1}{2\log^2x}\frac{1-x^2+(1+x^2)\log x}{x+1}\right|^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{-1}{2\log^2x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1-x^2+(1+x^2)\log x}{x+1}\right)dx\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{1}{2\log^2x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(1-x+\frac{(1+x^2)\log x}{x+1}\right)dx\\
&=\frac12\int^1_0\frac{1}{\log^2x}\left(-1+\frac{(1+x^2)}{x(x+1)}+\frac{(x^2+2x-1)\log x}{(x+1)^2}\right)dx\\
&=\frac12\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x}{x(x+1)\log^2x}+\frac{1}{\log x}-\frac{2}{(x+1)^2\log x}\right)dx\\
&=\frac12\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x}{x(x+1)\log^2x}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^2\log x}\right)dx+\frac12\int^1_0\left(\frac{1}{\log x}-\frac{4}{(x+1)^2\log x}\right)dx\\
&=\frac12(I_1+I_2).
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
I_1&=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x}{x(x+1)\log^2x}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^2\log x}\right)dx\\
&=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x^2+2x\log x}{(x+1)^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x\log^2x}\\
&=\left.\frac{-1}{\log x}\frac{1-x^2+2x\log x}{(x+1)^2}\right|^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{-1}{\log x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1-x^2+2x\log x}{(x+1)^2}\right)dx\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{-1}{\log x}\frac{-2(1-x)\log x}{(x+1)^3}dx\\
&=2\int^1_0\frac{1-x}{(x+1)^3}dx=\frac12.
\end{align*}$$

*Mathematica* is able to evaluate $I_2=12\log A-1-\frac43\log2$, so the conjectured closed form is proved.

Edit: to evaluate $I_2$, we write $F(a)=\int^1_0\frac{x^a-1}{(x+1)^2\log x}dx$, so that $F(0)=0$, and $F'(a)=\int^1_0\frac{x^a}{(x+1)^2}dx$. We have
$$\begin{align*}
I_2&=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1}{\log x}-\frac{4}{(x+1)^2\log x}\right)dx\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{x^2+2x-3}{(x+1)^2\log x}dx=F(2)+2F(1).
\end{align*}$$

Then we need to give closed form of $F(a)$. First we have 
$$\begin{align*}
\int^1_0\frac{x^adx}{(1-zx)^2}&=\int^1_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)z^nx^{n+a}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)z^n}{n+a+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n-a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n+a+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{a}{a+1}~_2F_1(1,a+1;a+2\mid z)
\end{align*}$$
for all $|z|<1$. Taking limits, we have 
$$\begin{align*}
F'(a)&=\frac12-\frac{a}{a+1}~_2F_1(1,a+1;a+2\mid-1)\\
&=\frac12-\frac{a}{2}\left(\psi\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\right)
\end{align*}$$
and therefore 
$$\begin{align*}
F(a)&=\int^a_0F'(b)~db\\
&=\frac{a}{2}-\int^a_0\frac{b}{2}\left(\psi\left(\frac{b+2}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)\right)db\\
&=\frac{a}{2}-2\int^{a/2}_{0}c\left(\psi(c+1)-\psi(c+\frac12)\right)dc\\
&=\frac{a}{2}+\int^{a/2}_{0}(2\psi(c+1)-\psi(c+\frac12))dc-2\int^{a/2}_{0}\left((c+1)\psi(c+1)-(c+\frac12)\psi(c+\frac12)\right)dc\\
&=\frac{a}{2}+(2\log\Gamma(a/2+1)-2\log\Gamma(1)-\log\Gamma(a/2+1/2)+\log\Gamma(1/2))\\
&-2\left(\int^{a/2+1}_{1}-\int^{a/2+1/2}_{1/2}\right)c\psi(c)dc\\
&=\frac{a}{2}+\log\Gamma(1/2)+2\log\Gamma(a/2+1)-\log\Gamma(a/2+1/2)-2\left.(c\log\Gamma(c)-\psi^{(-2)}(c))\right|^{a/2+1,1/2}_{a/2+1/2,1}\\
&=\frac{a}{2}+\log\Gamma(1/2)+2\log\Gamma(a/2+1)-\log\Gamma(a/2+1/2)-(a+2)\log\Gamma(a/2+1)\\&+(a+1)\log\Gamma(a/2+1/2)-\log\Gamma(1/2)+2\left.(\psi^{(-2)}(c))\right|^{a/2+1,1/2}_{a/2+1/2,1}\\
&=\frac{a}{2}-a\log\Gamma(a/2+1)+a\log\Gamma(a/2+1/2)+2\left.(\psi^{(-2)}(c))\right|^{a/2+1,1/2}_{a/2+1/2,1}\\
&=\frac{a}{2}-a\log\Gamma(a/2+1)+a\log\Gamma(a/2+1/2)\\
&+2\left(\psi^{(-2)}(a/2+1)-\psi^{(-2)}(a/2+1/2)+\psi^{(-2)}(1/2)-\psi^{(-2)}(1)\right).\\
\end{align*}$$
Here $\psi^{(-2)}(a)=\int^a_0\log\Gamma(x)dx$.
We can now give a closed form for $I_2$:
$$\begin{align*}
I_2&=F(2)+2F(1)\\
&=(1-2\log\Gamma(2)+2\log\Gamma(3/2))+2\left(1/2-\log\Gamma(3/2)+\log\Gamma(1)\right)\\
&+2(\psi^{(-2)}(2)-\psi^{(-2)}(3/2)+\psi^{(-2)}(1/2)-\psi^{(-2)}(1))\\
&+4(\psi^{(-2)}(3/2)-\psi^{(-2)}(1)+\psi^{(-2)}(1/2)-\psi^{(-2)}(1))\\
&=2+2\psi^{(-2)}(2)+2\psi^{(-2)}(3/2)+6\psi^{(-2)}(1/2)-10\psi^{(-2)}(1).
\end{align*}$$
Using the known values $\psi^{(-2)}(2)=\log2+\log\pi-1$, $\psi^{(-2)}(1)=\frac12\log2+\frac12\log\pi$, $\psi^{(-2)}(3/2)=\frac34\log\pi+\frac{5}{24}\log2+\frac32\log A-\frac12$ and $\psi^{(-2)}(1/2)=\frac14\log\pi+\frac{5}{24}\log 2+\frac32\log A$, we finally conclude that $I_2=12\log A-1-\frac43\log2$, and therefore $$I=\frac12(I_1+I_2)=6\log A-\frac23\log2-\frac14.$$

Comment: Nice work, but I respectfully disagree that evaluating the integral in Mathematica proves anything.

Comment: @RonGordon: Could you do it without contour integration, the residue theorem and other complex analysis tools?

Comment: @Lucian: In fact, I have so far worked it out to a certain point as a real integral, but am currently stuck and unfortunately, work calls.  To be devil's advocate, there is likely a way that would use contour integration, but that way is not obvious to me yet.

Comment: Chen, the trouble with Mathematica is that unfortunately it does not reveal to us the methods by which it arrives at the result... and we're really curious as to precisely that particular piece of information. :-)

Comment: The second part is done using polygamma functions.

Comment: [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) we can relate $\psi^{(-2)}(x)$ to the Barnes G-function, and use the values of the G-function on the page.

Comment: Nice work chen Weng much more elegant than mine.