# How to set up partial fractions?

Tags: logarithms, partial-fractions

I have set up partial fractions so that$$A\ln^3x-B(x+x^2)=1-x^2$$ and $$ C\ln^3x+D(x+x^2)=1+x^2$$ to set up and solve the following  $$\alpha(1+x)+ \gamma x= A+C$$ and from $$\frac {D \ln x-B}{\ln^3x} \to  $$ $$\frac {\Delta \ln x}{\ln^2 x}-\frac {\beta}{\ln x}\to$$ $$\frac{\Delta}{\ln x}-\frac{\beta}{\ln x}=\frac {D \ln x-B}{\ln^3x}$$

Assuming A,B,C,and, D are either constants or functions of x, and  $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\space and \space \Delta$ are likewise constants or functions of x, how do I solve for these?

Guess I should post the rest of my work (I didn't because I did not want to make a duplicate.

Note this work comes from  my attempt to solve  [Oskansa's Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705969/integral-int-01-frac1-x2-left1x2-right-ln-x-leftxx2-right-ln3x)

Here it is

Start with the original derivative $$ \frac {(1-x^2)+(1+x^2)\ln x}{(x+x^2)\ln^3x}dx$$ Break the fraction in the normal way so that  you have $$\frac{(1-x^2)}{(x+x^2)\ln^3x}+\frac{(1+x^2)}{(x+x^2)\ln^2x)}$$ Now break it again so that $$\frac{A}{x+x^2}-\frac{B}{\ln^3x}=\frac{(1-x^2)}{(x+x^2)\ln^3x} $$ and $$\frac{C}{x+x^2}+\frac{D}{\ln^2x}=\frac{(1+x^2)}{(x+x^2)\ln^2x)}$$ So now the derivative is $$\frac{A}{x+x^2}-\frac{B}{\ln^3x}+ \frac{C}{x+x^2}+\frac{D}{\ln^2x}dx=$$ $$\frac{A+C}{x+x^2}+ \frac{D\ln x-B}{\ln^3x}dx$$ Then break them again so that $$\frac {\alpha}{x}+\frac{\gamma}{1+x}= \frac{A+C}{x+x^2}$$ and $$\frac {\nu lnx}{ln^2x}-\frac {\beta}{\ln x}= \frac {\nu}{\ln x}-\frac {\beta}{\ln x}=\frac{D\ln x-B}{\ln^3x}dx$$ then the integral becomes $$I =\int \frac {\alpha}{x}+\int\frac{\gamma}{1+x}+\int \frac {\nu}{\ln x}-\int\frac{\beta}{\ln x}\space dx=$$

NOTE $\nu$ in this solution =$\Delta$ in this OP.

Comment: Partial fractions is a tool for rational functions.  Rational functions are ratios of two polynomials.  Polynomials are sums of powers of $x$.  $\ln x$ and $\ln^3 x$ are not powers of $x$.

Comment: No, but shouldn't I be able to do the same thing I do with $x^3$ in the denominator? That is decompose it to $\frac {a}{x} + \frac {b}{x^2}$?

Comment: If your denominator is a polynomial, then you may do partial fractions.  If your denominator is not a polynomial, then no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** To use *partial fraction decomposition*,  the numerator and denominator must be *polynomials.* (I.e., partial fractions work with *rational functions*.) The factor of $\ln^3 x$ in the denominator tells us immediately that the denominator is *not* a polynomial.

---

Note that in your originally posted function, the denominator factors to $$(x^2 + x)\ln^3(x) = x(x+1)\ln^3 x$$

I can't remember the numerator, off-hand, but you *can* split it into two integrals (there were two terms in it).

**Edit**

With the edit to the question: Note that the first of the "split integral": $$\frac{(1-x^2)}{(x+x^2)ln^3x} = \dfrac{(1-x)(1+x)}{x(1+x)\ln^3 x} = \dfrac{1-x}{x\ln^3 x} = \dfrac{1}{x\ln^3 x} - \dfrac 1{\ln^3 x}$$ In the first term, you can substitute $u = \ln x \implies du = \dfrac 1x \,dx$. That gives you $$\int \dfrac 1{x\ln^3(x)}\,dx = \int \dfrac{\,du}{u^3} = \int u^{-3}\,du$$

Comment: the factor $ln^3X$ = $ln^2X(lnx)$

Comment: Sure, which is equal to $\ln(X)\ln(X)\ln(X)$, but this is NOT a polynomial!

Comment: Hopefully the edit explains a bit more...though it probably changes nothing

Comment: Note that the first of the "split integral": $$\frac{(1-x^2)}{(x+x^2)ln^3x} = \dfrac{(1-x)(1+x)}{x(1+x)\ln^3 x} = \dfrac{1-x}{x\ln^3 x} = \dfrac{1}{x\ln^3 x} - \dfrac 1{\ln^3 x}$$ In the first term, you can substitute $u = \ln x \implies du = \dfrac 1x \,dx$. That gives you $$\int \dfrac 1{x\ln^3(x)}\,dx = \int \dfrac{\,du}{u^3} = \int u^{-3}\,du$$

Comment: I see then $x=e^u$

Comment: Yes, it would, but that's not needed. Note that the $x$ in the denominator gives us the needed $du = \frac 1x\,dx$. Once we integrate $u^{-3} du$, we replace $u$ with $\ln x$.

Comment: The second integral would then be $\int \frac{1}{xln^2}+\frac{1}{ln^2X}$

Comment: Not to sound like a pouting child but I would like to know WHY $ln^ax$ does not work in partial fractions. I understand the fact that it does not, but I want to know the  the actual in number theory behind the negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use partial fractions for this.  The standard method of partial fractions only works if the original function is a *rational function*, that is, a polynomial divided by a polynomial.  The $\ln$ term throws this right out.

You could possibly get something like partial fractions when other than polynomials are involved, but as far as I know there is no systematic way of doing it.  You would have to use trial and error, and I should say the chance of success would be pretty small.

However you don't need all this to do the integral - it is actually a fairly routine integral which has been dressed up to make it look harder.  **Hint**.  Factorise the polynomials in the numerator and denominator and see what you notice.

**Note**.  I'm referring to the integral in the title of the question but it seems that it has just been removed. . . so I'm no longer entirely sure what you want to ask.

Comment: Yeah well at least it LOOKED pretty. And I learned another rule to ad  the many things I can't do.