# $\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{(t-2)\ln t}\,dt$ integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I have two related questions. The first is: Is there a closed form expression for:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{(t-2)\ln t}\,dt\approx0.507834$$
I know that there are some very superb integrators on this site. I doubt that a closed form exists, but I may be wrong. If I'm wrong, I'm curious as to how you got your answer! (P.S. [This page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705969/integral-int-01-frac1-x2-left1x2-right-ln-x-leftxx2-right-ln3x) gives me hope that it might be expressable in terms of $\zeta(\cdot)$. If so, I'd consider that to be "closed form.")

Second question: Is there an elementary function $f(t)$ such that:
$$\exp\left(\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{(t-2)\ln t}\,dt\right)=\int_0^1f(t)dt$$
That value is approximately $1.66169$. I am very interested in this value. The expression on the left is a great way to express this number. But, I feel like it would be "cleaner" if I could express it simply as an integral, like on the right.

Comment: I'd start by substituting $-u=\log t$.

Comment: Good idea - that changes the limits from "0 to 1" to "0 to infinity." At that point we can use contour integration (maybe? I've only had a brief introduction to it so far).

Answer (score 2):

The value of your integral could be expressed as $$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{2^n}=-\frac{d}{ds}\Phi\left(\frac12,0,0\right)=-\frac12\frac{d}{ds}\Phi\left(\frac12,0,1\right),$$
where $$\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(n+a)^s}$$
is the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html). The second value you're interested in, surprisingly, has its own name: [Somos' quadratic recurrence constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos'_quadratic_recurrence_constant):
$$\exp I=\sigma=\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\ldots}}}=1^{1/2}2^{1/4}3^{1/8}\ldots$$

Here's the proof of the series representation. Using that $$\frac{1}{2-t}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{2^{n+1}},$$
we can write
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}-t^n}{\ln t}\,dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1},$$
since
$$\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}-t^n}{\ln t}\,dt=\int_0^1\left(\int_{n}^{n+1}t^y\,dy\right)\,dt=\int_{n}^{n+1}\left(\int_0^1t^y\,dt\right)\,dy=$$$$=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dy}{y+1}=\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1}.$$
Therefore,
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\ln\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n}}\ln\frac{n+1}{n}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n+1)}{2^{n+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n}{2^n}.$$

Comment: I must admit: I actually *started* with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{2^n}$, and then I worked my way to an integral. (My hope was that I'd be able to evaluate the integral, and thus get a closed form for the sum.) So this tells me nothing, except for the part about Lerch transcendents. (Well, no - this tells me that it is very unlikely for me to find a closed form solution.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Well, then you're right, there's no reason to expect anything better. Otherwise, I think, this constant (with a name!) very likely would have been computed in terms of other known constants. It actually appears in some papers just as it is or in terms of Lerch transcendents.

Comment: Alternatively, you can express the integral as a polylog derivative, which is slightly more familiar then Lerch.

Comment: @DavidH Like this: $\displaystyle\frac{d}{ds}\left.\mbox{Li}_s\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|_{s=0}$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw I believe there should be a negative sign out front, but otherwise yes.

Comment: @DavidH You are correct, I did forget the sign.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t \over \pars{t - 2}\ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t \approx 0.507834:
     \ {\large ?}}$.

> Lets consider
>   $$
> {\cal F}\pars{\mu}\equiv
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{\mu} \over \pars{t - 2}\ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t\,,\qquad\qquad
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
> {\cal F}\pars{1} & = & {\large ?}
> \\[1mm]
> {\cal F}\pars{0} & = & 0
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

\begin{align}
{\cal F}'\pars{\mu}&
=\int_{0}^{1}{-t^{\mu}\ln\pars{t} \over \pars{t - 2}\ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{1}{t^{\mu} \over 2 - t}\,\dd t
=\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1/2}t^{\mu + n - 1}\pars{1/2}^{n - 1}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{1/2}^{n} \over \mu + n}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t \over \pars{t - 2}\ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t&={\cal F}\pars{1}
> =\int_{0}^{1}{\cal F}'\pars{\mu}\,\dd\mu
> =\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{n}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + n} - \ln\pars{n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{n - 1}\ln\pars{n}
> -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{n}\ln\pars{n}
> =\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\ln\pars{n}
> \end{align}

Also $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ \verts{z} < 1~}}$,
$$
\partiald{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}{\rm s}
=\partiald{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}z^{n}/n^{\rm s}}{\rm s}
=-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{z^{n} \over n^{\rm s}}\,\ln\pars{n}
$$
such that
$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t \over \pars{t - 2}\ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t
=-\lim_{{\rm s}\ \to\ 0}\partiald{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{1/2}}{\rm s}}
\approx {\tt 0.5078}
$$

Comment: Which is the same as:$$\displaystyle-\frac{d}{ds}\left.\mbox{Li}_s\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|_{s=0}‌​$$except with a notational difference.

Comment: @columbus8myhw That's quite true. Thanks.