# How to find ${\large\int}_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x \left(1+x^2\right) \ln^2 x} \mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form

Please help me to find a closed form for this integral:
$$
I=\int_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x \left(1+x^2\right) \ln^2 x} \mathrm dx
$$

Routine textbook methods for this complicated integral fail.

Comment: I feel like it's becoming a trend to ask questions about practically impossible integrals...

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the integral $~J(n)=\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}x^n~dx$, and notice that $I=J^{^{(-2)}}(0)$. With or without the substitution $x=\dfrac1t$ , express this integral as a linear combination of the [polygamma functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) $\psi_{_0}$ and $\psi_{_1}$ whose arguments are linear expressions in *n*.

Comment: A somewhat similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/705969/88895

Comment: Which book did you find this question in ?

Comment: Why try to close this beautiful topic. What happens here?

Comment: Delete voters, would this site really be better off without this question and its answers?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here is another Feynman's way to evaluate the integral. Set $x=\frac1t$, then
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x \left(1+x^2\right) \ln^2 x}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{t-1-t\ln t}{(1+t^2)\ln^2t}\ dt.
$$
Now consider
$$
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)=\int_0^1t^\alpha\cdot\frac{t-1-t\ln t}{(1+t^2)\ln^2t}\ dt.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2\mathcal{I}}{d\alpha^2}&=\int_0^1\frac{t^\alpha}{1+t^2}(t-1-t\ln t)\ dt\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{2n+\alpha}(t-1-t\ln t)\ dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^1\left(t^{2n+\alpha+1}-t^{2n+\alpha}-t^{2n+\alpha+1}\ln t\right)\ dt\tag1\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac{1}{2n+\alpha+2}-\frac{1}{2n+\alpha+1}+\frac{1}{(2n+\alpha+2)^2}\right]\tag2\\
&=-\frac14\left[\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+4}{4}\right)\right]+\frac14\left[\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+3}{4}\right)\right]\\
&\quad+\frac1{16}\left[\psi_1\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{4}\right)-\psi_1\left(\frac{\alpha+4}{4}\right)\right]\tag3\\
\frac{d\mathcal{I}}{d\alpha}&=-\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{4}\right)+\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+4}{4}\right)+\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{4}\right)-\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+3}{4}\right)\\
&\quad+\frac14\left[\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+4}{4}\right)\right]\tag4\\
&=\ln\Gamma\left[\frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+4)}{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+3)}\right]+\frac14\left[\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+4}{4}\right)\right]\tag5\\
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)&=\int\ln\Gamma\left[\frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+4)}{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+3)}\right]\ d\alpha+\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+2}{4}\right)-\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+4}{4}\right).
\end{align}
Since $0<t<1$, then as $\alpha\to\infty$, implying $\mathcal{I}(\alpha)\to0$ and $\mathcal{I}'(\alpha)\to0$. Thus

> $$
> \mathcal{I}(0)=\int_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x \left(1+x^2\right) \ln^2 x}\ dx=\color{blue}{\frac{\ln2}6+\frac{\ln\pi}2-6\ln A+\frac2\pi G},
> $$

where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) and $G$ is the [Catalan constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).

---

**Notes :**

[$\displaystyle(1)\ \ \int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(\alpha+1)^{n+1}}, \qquad\text{for }\  n=0,1,2,\ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905818/123277)

[$\displaystyle(2)\ \ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(z+k)^{m+1}}=\frac1{(-2)^{m+1}m!}\left[\psi_{m}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-\psi_{m}\left(\frac{z+1}{2}\right)\right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905818/123277)

[$\displaystyle(3)\ \ \psi_{m}(z) := \frac{d^m}{dz^m} \psi(z) = \frac{d^{m+1}}{dz^{m+1}} \ln\Gamma(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)

[$\displaystyle(4)\ \ \int\ln\Gamma(z)\ dz=\frac{z(1-z)}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\log 2\pi +z\log\Gamma(z) -\log \text{G}(1+z)+C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function#Relation_to_the_Loggamma_integral),

$\qquad$where $\text{G}(\cdot)$ is the Barnes G-function and $C$ is a constant of integration. Also for $a,b>0$
$$
\int\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x+a}{b}\right)\ dx=b\ \psi^{(-2)}\left(\frac{x+a}{b}\right)+C.
$$

$\displaystyle(5)\ \ $As $\alpha\to\infty$, both of sides tend to $0$, hence the constant of integration is $0$.

Answer (score 57):

$$I=\frac{\ln2}6+\frac{\ln\pi}2-6\ln A+\frac2\pi G,$$
where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) and $G$ is the [Catalan constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).

Answer (score 33):

Let's give a (sketch of the) proof of the following closed form evaluation.

> $$
> I=\int_1^\infty\frac{1-x+\ln x}{x \left(1+x^2\right) \ln^2 x} \mathrm dx=\frac{\ln2}6+\frac{\ln\pi}2-6\ln A+\frac2\pi G,
> $$

where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) and $G$ is the [Catalan constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).

Observe that, by the change of variable $\displaystyle u=\frac 1x$, we have
$$
I=\int_0^1\frac{u-1-u\ln u}{\left(1+u^2\right) \ln^2 u} \mathrm du=\int_0^1\frac{(1-u^2)(u-1-u\ln u)}{\left(1-u^4\right) \ln^2 u} \mathrm du.
$$
We set
$$
I(s):=\int_0^1u^s\frac{(1-u^2)(u-1-u\ln u)}{\left(1-u^4\right) \ln^2 u} \mathrm du, \quad s\geq0.
$$

We are allowed to differentiate $I(s)$  twice to obtain
$$
I''(s)=\int_0^1u^s\frac{(1-u^2)(u-1-u\ln u)}{\left(1-u^4\right)} \mathrm du. 
$$
Using the standard expansion $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-u^4}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{4k}, \, |u|<1,$ and performing the termwise integration, 
$$
\begin{align}
I''(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1u^{s+4k}(1-u^2)(u-1-u\ln u) \mathrm du
\end{align}
$$ 
gives
$$
\begin{align}
I''(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(4k+2+s)^2}-\frac{1}{(4k+4+s)^2}+\frac{1}{(4k+2+s)}-\frac{1}{(4k+1+s)}\right).
\end{align}
$$ 
Now, recall the following series representation of the digamma function $\displaystyle \psi : = \Gamma'/\Gamma$,
$$
\psi(u+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{u+k}  
\right), \quad u >-1, 
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and, by differentiation, giving$$
\psi'(u+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(u+k)^2}, \quad u>-1.
$$
Hence
$$
I''(s)=\frac{1}{16}\psi'\left(\frac{s+2}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{16}\psi'\left(\frac{s+4}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\psi\left(\frac{s+4}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\psi\left(\frac{s+1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\psi\left(\frac{s+3}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\psi\left(\frac{s+2}{4}\right).
$$
We have, as $s \rightarrow +\infty$, $I(s) \rightarrow 0$ and $I'(s) \rightarrow 0$, leading to
$$
I(s)=\log \Gamma \left(\frac{s+2}{4}\right)-\log \Gamma \left(\frac{s+4}{4}\right) +  
 4 \left(\psi\left(-2, \frac{s+4}{4}\right) + \psi\left(-2, \frac{s+1}{4}\right) - 
    \psi\left(-2, \frac{s+2}{4}\right) - \psi\left(-2, \frac{s+3}{4}\right)\right),
$$
then, with the use of Wolfram Alpha, as $s \rightarrow 0$ we get

$$
I=I(0)=\frac{\ln2}6+\frac{\ln\pi}2-6\ln A+\frac2\pi G.
$$

Comment: This is a good and nice answer ! Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the kind words.

Comment: Be sure that my words are not kind ! They are just sincere. What you gave us here is **an** answer and not just a result. "Dont give a child a fish but show him how to fish” said Mao Tse-tung.

Comment: This was my favourite answer thanks to your detailed exposition.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> In this answer, I'll show a $\ds{\ \ul{quite\ short\ path} }$ to an integration in terms of $\ds{\ \ul{just\ a\ pair}\ }$ of *Digamma*'s functions.

Sooner or later, I'll need the following integral:

> \begin{align}
> &\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
> \ds{\quad\left.\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\,
> \right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{t}\ >\ -1}\quad}
> \\ \\ \hline
> \end{array} =
> \int_{0}^{1}{x^{t} - x^{t + 2} \over 1 - x^{4}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm] = &\
> {1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\pars{t - 3}/4} - x^{\pars{t - 1}/4} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x =
> {1 \over 4}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\pars{t - 1}/4} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> -
> \int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{\pars{t - 3}/4} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm] = &\
> \begin{array}{|c|}\hline \\
> \ds{\quad{1 \over 4}\bracks{%
> \Psi\pars{t + 3 \over 4} - \Psi\pars{t + 1 \over 4}}\quad}
> \\  \\ \hline
> \end{array}\tag{1}
> \\&
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the *Digamma Function* and we used the standard integral representation of it. Namely,
>   $\ds{\left.\vphantom{\huge A}\Psi\pars{z}\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{z}\ >\ 0}\
> =\ -\gamma + \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{z - 1} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t.\ }$ $\ds{\gamma}$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*.

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} &  \equiv
\int_{1}^{\infty}{1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over x \pars{1 + x^{2}}\ln^{2}\pars{x}}
\,\dd x\ \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\
\int_{0}^{1}{x - 1 - x\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}\ln^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{1}\underbrace{%
\bracks{{x \over \ln\pars{x}} + {1 - x \over \ln^{2}\pars{x}}}}
_{\ds{\vphantom{\Large A}\color{#f00}{?}}}\
\,{\dd x \over 1 + x^{2}}\tag{2}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\mbox{Note that}\quad\
\overbrace{{x \over \ln\pars{x}} + {1 - x \over \ln^{2}\pars{x}}}
^{\ds{\color{#f00}{\vphantom{\Large A}?}}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{1}t\,x^{t}\,\dd t\tag{3}
\end{equation}
This identity can be straightforward derived by performing two successive integration by parts with the identity $\ds{x^{t} = {1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\partiald{x^{t}}{t}}$

---

By replacing $\pars{3}$ in $\pars{2}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} & =
-\int_{0}^{1}t\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd t =
-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}t\bracks{\Psi\pars{t + 3 \over 4} -
\Psi\pars{t + 1 \over 4}}\,\dd t\quad
\pars{~\mbox{see}\ \pars{1}~}
\\[3mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}t\,\partiald{}{t}
\ln\pars{\Gamma^{\,4}\pars{\bracks{t + 3}/4} \over
\Gamma^{\,4}\pars{\bracks{t + 1}/4}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}
\ln\pars{\Gamma^{\,4}\pars{1} \over \Gamma^{\,4}\pars{1/2}} +
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 3 \over 4}}\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1 \over 4}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =
\half\,\ln\pars{\pi} +
4\int_{-1/4}^{0}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t -
4\int_{-3/4}^{-1/2}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[8mm] & =
\half\,\ln\pars{\pi}
\\[3mm] & -
4\int_{0}^{-1/4}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t -
4\int_{0}^{-1/2}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t +
4\int_{0}^{-3/4}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t\tag{4}
\end{align}
I'll use the [well know identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.17.E4)
( $\ds{\mathrm{G}}$ is the  [Barnes $\mathrm{G}$-Function or/and Double Gamma Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.17)
 )
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{z}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] = &\
\half\,z\ln\pars{2\pi} - \half\,z\pars{z + 1} + z\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z + 1}} -
\ln\pars{\mathrm{G}\pars{z + 1}}
\end{align}
which, for $\ds{\ul{z \in \mathbb{R}}}$, is conveniently written as
$$
\int_{0}^{z}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t =
\half\,z\ln\pars{2\pi} -
\ln\pars{\exp\pars{z\pars{z + 1} \over 2}
\Gamma^{\, -z}\pars{z + 1}\,\mathrm{G}\pars{z + 1}}
$$
It leads to explicit expressions for the integrals in $\ds{\pars{4}}$:
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\int_{0}^{-1/4}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{1 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{2\pi} -
\ln\pars{\expo{-3/32}\ \Gamma^{1/4}\pars{3 \over 4}\mathrm{G}\pars{3 \over 4}}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\int_{0}^{-1/2}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2\pi} - \ln\pars{\expo{-1/8}\ \Gamma^{1/2}\pars{\half}\mathrm{G}\pars{\half}}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\int_{0}^{-3/4}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{3 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{2\pi} -
\ln\pars{\expo{-3/32}\ \Gamma^{3/4}\pars{1 \over 4}\mathrm{G}\pars{1 \over 4}}}
\end{array}\right.\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Fortunately, in terms of the [Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html) $\ds{A}$ and the [Catalan Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html) $\ds{K}$, the above $\ds{\ul{\ln\mbox{-arguments}}}$ are given in the [MathWorld G-Barnes Function page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) as formulas $\ds{\pars{17}}$, $\ds{\pars{19}}$ and $\ds{\vphantom{\Large A}\pars{16}}$, respectively:
\begin{align}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\expo{-3/32}\ \Gamma^{1/4}\pars{3 \over 4}\mathrm{G}\pars{3 \over 4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{A^{-9/8}\ \expo{K/\pars{4\pi}}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\expo{-1/8}\ \Gamma^{1/2}\pars{\half}\mathrm{G}\pars{\half}} & \ds{=} & \ds{A^{-3/2\,\,2^{1/24}}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\expo{-3/32}\ \Gamma^{3/4}\pars{1 \over 4}\mathrm{G}\pars{1 \over 4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{A^{-9/8}\ \expo{-K/\pars{4\pi}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
The integrals in expressions $\ds{\pars{5}}$ become:
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\int_{0}^{-1/4}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{1 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{2\pi} + {9 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{A} - {K \over 4\pi}
\approx -0.0228}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\int_{0}^{-1/2}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2\pi} + {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{A} -
{1 \over 24}\,\ln\pars{2} \approx -0.1152}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\int_{0}^{-3/4}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{3 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{2\pi} + {9 \over 8}\,\ln\pars{A} + {K \over 4\pi}
\approx -0.3365}
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}
\end{equation}

---

The final result is given by inserting these expressions into result $\ds{\pars{4}}$:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\ \\
\ds{\quad\color{#f00}{I} = \int_{1}^{\infty}{1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over
x\pars{1 + x^{2}}\ln^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\color{#f00}{%
{2K \over \pi} - 6\ln\pars{A} + \half\,\ln\pars{\pi} + {1 \over 6}\,\ln\pars{2}}
\approx -0.2215\quad}
\\ \ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$