# How to prove the following using residue theorem?

Tags: complex-numbers, analyticity

I have this HW and I don't know how to approach it, does anybody know how can it be shown that $$∑_{n=1}^∞\frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{π^2}{6}$$ using residue theorem?

Comment: This is not a physics question. It belongs on [math.se]

Comment: [Complex Variables - Schaum's Outline Series by Spiegel-Lipschutz S.-Schiller-Spellman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZaqs.jpg)

Comment: It has been done by tired [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1863391/44121) and [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro) is a *must*.

Comment: Can you apply the residue theorem to $\int_{|z| = 2\pi (N+1/2)} \frac{z^{-2}}{e^z-1}dz$ ? Do you see why $\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{|z| = 2\pi (N+1/2)} \frac{z^{-2}}{e^z-1}dz= 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In four dense pages in this [paper](http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/MathGradTalkZeta2.pdf) the author starts with the residue theorem on page 7 and proves that $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6.$ I skimmed the article and it looks like a clear exposition to me.  There are certainly other versions.

The paper is by Brendan Sullivan, *Numerous Proofs of* $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$ dated 2013.

Comment: I can not thank you enough)

Comment: @yasiren: no problem. actually the proof is shorter than i thought--maybe two and a half pages, and nothing very complicated.

Comment: I cannot imagine what satisfaction people get from doing other people's homework for them.

Comment: @WillO: Neither my ref. nor those in the comments will do the OP's HW for him/her, and I don't assume bad faith on the part of the questioner.